# Emacs (gui) font resets on startup

Tags: emacs, fonts

I have tried the following at the very end of my Emacs init file:

```
(set-frame-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-6")
(set-default-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-6")
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "DejaVu Sans Mono-6" :height 100)
```

When starting Emacs (GUI), while it's loading it's modules etc. I can see the font changing to the correct one, but at det very last second the window blinks and the font is reset to something like Terminus.

After Emacs has started, I can eval the code above, and the font sets correctly.

Im using [bbatsov's prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) with Emacs 24.3.1, from offical repos.

Anyone know what is causing it to reset, and what I can do to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Bisect your init file recursively, find what causes the font to change back to Terminus.

   To do that, comment out half of it, then 3/4, then 7/8,... checking each time to narrow it down further.
2. If it turns out that the problem is Prelude-specific, report the problem to Prelude's maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be prelude.

I though prelude loaded the `personal/init.el` file, and that was that, but it loads all in the `personal` dir, in alphabetical order (as seen in the bottom of prelude's `init.el`).

By modifing it to load the `personal/init.el` last, things worked.